# Seating four people next to each other probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The following problem is from Carol Ash's *The Probability Tutoring Book*

If $4$ people are assigned seats at random in a $7$ seat row, what is the probability that they are seated together?

My approach:

We can choose $4$ from $7$ seats: $_{7}C_4$ ways,

We can permute the people in $4!$ ways.

So, my answer was $\frac{4!}{_{7}C_4}$

However the answer in the book is $\frac{4}{_{7}C_4}$. did they miss the factorial? Or is this the correct answer?

Why is the numerator just $4$?

Is it because if I permute the numerator, I also have to permute the denominator? Can someone explain why this is logically so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be clear whether you are using permutations or combinations.

If you want to use permutations, $Pr =\dfrac{4!\cdot4}{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}$

whereas if you want to use combinations, $Pr = \dfrac{4}{\binom7 4}$

Whenever *probability* is asked for, it is generally simpler to use combinations

Answer (score 1):

What is your logic in using 4! ? If you choose 1 to 4, ..., 4 to 7, you can place the people in different permutations in the same consecutive seating. $$A-B-C-D$$ $$1-2-3-4$$ Or $$A-C-B-D$$ $$1-2-3-4$$ and so on but this is technically the same seating. $1-2-3-4$ or 2 to 5 and so on is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that all 4 people must be seated in a row, so all the possible outcomes are : the seats from $1$ to $4$, from $2$ to $5$, from $3$ to $6$, and from $ 4$ to $7$.

Hence, there are 4 possible configuration, then they can be permuted $_{7}C_4$ ways, hence the total result is :

$$\frac{4}{_{7}C_4} $$